# Reformat a Partitioned Mac OS Extended External Disk?

Tags: time-machine, disk-utility, partition

One of my backup disks is full. How can I Erase & Reformat the drive? I use Yosemite OS.

The External Hard Drive was formatted as Partitioned Mac OS Extended (case sensitive, Journaled, Encrypted volume) Disk.

I tried under "Disk Utilities", but got this Error Message:

> Disk Encryption failed with the error:  Unable to delete the Core
>   Storage logical volume group.

Comment: As first step you should turn off the encryption. Did you do that ?

Comment: No.Do you mean Turn Off the Mac Encryption in Fire Vault?

Comment: No.Do you mean Turn Off the Mac Encryption in Fire Vault?Or, Backup Disk Encryption via Time Machine?

Comment: You could enter the gpt command in a Terminal window to erase all partitions from the external disk. This would require you to be comfortable using Terminal.

Comment: DaR, if you what Buscar웃 to be notified that you posted a comment, you need include @Buscar somewhere in your comment.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Actually since Buscar's comment was the only one, the notification gets fired automatically. The ping is only needed when there are already multiple comments from multiple users.

Comment: @onik David is right, I did not get notes from DaR.

Answer (score 3):

This is an example of a procedure to erase an external disk containing a single encrypted partition.

1. Open the Disk Utility application and highlight the "Logical Volume
   Group" representing your external disk. An example is shown below.
   (Hint: click on image for a better view.)

   [image]
2. Next, click the Info icon to get the pop up window. Note, in the
   example shown below, the "Physical Backing" is disk1s2. This means
   the physical disk number is 1. The "s2" suffix can be ignored. Your
   numbers may be different.

   [image]
3. Next, highlight the "Encrypted Logical Partition" as shown in the
   example below.

   [image]
4. Again, click the Info icon to get a pop up window. Note the "Disk
   Identifier". In the example shown below, the value is disk2. Your
   value may be different.

   [image]
5. Close the Disk Utility and open the Terminal application. Enter the
   following commands. If your numbers differed from mine, make the
   appropriate substitutions. If prompted, enter your login password.

   ```
   diskutil  unmountDisk  /dev/disk2
   sudo  gpt  destroy  /dev/disk1
   sudo  gpt  create  -f  /dev/disk1
   ```

   When I entered these commands, I saw the following in the Terminal
   window.

   ```
   Steelhead:~ davidanderson$ diskutil  unmountDisk  /dev/disk2
   Unmount of all volumes on disk2 was successful
   Steelhead:~ davidanderson$ sudo  gpt  destroy  /dev/disk1
   Password:
   Steelhead:~ davidanderson$ sudo  gpt  create  -f  /dev/disk1
   Steelhead:~ davidanderson$
   ```

   The `distutil` command  must successfully unmount the disk in order
   for the gpt commands to work. If the disk will not unmount, then
   some window needs to be closed. Do not proceed with the gpt
   commands, if you can not unmount the disk.
6. If successful, you should see a result similar to what is shown
   below. The result shown is a 4GB flash drive with no partitions. You
   can either add a partition or repartition the entire drive.

   [image]